# Git branch files changed from command line

Tags: git, github

I understand that I can use `git diff master` to see how my feature branch is different from the master branch. I'm only interested in changes made by this particular branch, though, not changes on master. On GitHub, I can see the files changed under the "Files changed" tab of a pull request. How can I get the same list of files from the command line?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the `--name-only` option to `git diff`:

```
$ git diff --name-only master...<feature branch>
```

Comment: The triple-dot notation is the important bit here. It means "from where the branches diverged".